# Capybara testing if page has regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rspec, capybara

I'm new to RSpec and Capybara and I am trying to test if page has a time on it. 12:00 or 14:24 or 08:12 are good examples of what I am trying to test for.

I am using the following regex:

```
/^\d{2}:\d{2}/
```

I am not sure how to "phrase it" in capybara to test if the page contains this regex.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'd suppose something like

```
page.text.should match(/^\d{2}:\d{2}/)
```

or, with the new RSpec syntax

```
expect(page.text).to match(/^\d{2}:\d{2}/)
```

Or you can test not the whole page but some element, e.g.

```
find("span.time").text.should match(/^\d{2}:\d{2}/)
```

Comment: Thank you! Will page.text be deprecated?

Comment: I believe not, at least not in the nearest future. Seems like lots of people use it and consider it reads good. For more details see [this blog post](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax)

Comment: Note that retrieving content and then using non-Capybara matchers on the result breaks the Capybara functionality of waiting for a match to occur. Using this solution, you'll likely retrieve the text before the work has been done to put the text there that you are looking for. I would go so far as to say this is a Capybara anti-pattern.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this is new behavior, but you can just use `has_content?`:

`page.has_content?(/do not have permission/i)`

In rspec, that would be something like this:

`expect(page).to have_content(/do not have permission/i)`

I found this in the [online documentation for capybara](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_text%3F-instance_method), but it's under `has_text?` since `has_content?` is just an alias.

Comment: Unfortunately Capybara does not support case insensitive searches per the [DSL documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#the-dsl)

Comment: That's for the xpath searching, not the matchers.  `have_content` is defined by `has_content`, an alias for `has_text`, which relies on `assert_text`, which takes a regex.  Ruby regex engine determines how a regex matches something, not capybara's DSL.  https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/1a9417061c08194d9c4332cbbac186798cd5978a/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L435